Jenkins and okta integration with only username based login
We have integrated jenkins and okta. While opening jenkins URL, its redirecting to Okta page with username and password inputs.
However, we also want to allow the login only based on the username. This is because client side IAM integration with Okta only allow the login with username. When we provide username and password both then Okta logs shows that FAILURE: PASSWORD_BASED_LOGIN_DISALLOWED.
What we need if possible that, When we open jenkins URL, it redirects to Okta page and ask only for username. This username information then pass to Okta and then eventually gets the login.
